# SPI enabled in device tree, but I can't use it

Tags: spi, device-tree

I am trying to use SPI interface on Raspberry Pi 1 B (OS: Raspbian July 2017, kerenl 4.9.5). To do this, I  am using wiringPi. I confirmed that wiringPi works via `gpio readall`

To load SPI:

```
gpio load spi
```

But this gives me an error:

```
gpio: Unable to load/unload modules as this Pi has the device tree enabled.
  You need to run the raspi-config program (as root) and select the
  modules (SPI or I2C) that you wish to load/unload there and reboot.
  There is more information here:
      https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=97314
```

Strangely, `spidev` exists is under `/dev` (Does it mean SPI is loaded?)

```
ls /dev/spi*
/dev/spidev0.0  /dev/spidev0.1
```

Anyway, to fix the problem, the link in the error message tells me to:

1. Run `[sudo] raspi-config` and enable SPI: I did it and reboot Rpi

   - Did it, but didn't solve the problem.
2. If (1) did not work, edit `/boot/config.txt` and add `dtparam=spi=on`.

   - Did it, but didn't solve the problem.

And [the official device tree document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md) says one can disable device  tree by editing `/boot/config.txt` to have

```
device_tree=
```

But when it is done and reboot, only Rainbow splash appears and boot process never go further.

Can anyone give me an advice what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you can disable device tree anymore, that was intended to be a temporary directive to smooth the introduction of device tree.

Just add the device tree SPI entry.  Do not use `gpio load spi`.  That is deprecated.

As long as there `/dev/spidev*` entries you can use SPI.

To summarise

1. remove `device_tree=` from `/boot/config.txt`
2. add `dtparam=spi=on` to `/boot/config.txt`
3. do not use `gpio load spi`

Comment: Ok, then seems I did something wrong elsewhere. Thank you.