# SPI doesn't work because of device tree

Tags: spi, device-tree

I have the same problem as this person:
[SPI enabled in device tree, but I can't use it](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70785/spi-enabled-in-device-tree-but-i-cant-use-it/70786#70786?newreg=f465f8c5463e42e0a7ec337729476c66)

I tried commenting in the original thread but the community rules don't allow me to comment because I don't have 50 reputation points. The approved answer doesn't solve my problem.

[EDIT]

I've verified the pin is correct and I can light an LED by setting it high. This is true for both SCLK (pin 23, GPIO11) and MOSI (pin 19, GPIO10). I'm trying to drive some Adafruit DotStar LED's. If I don't set the pins high or low, SCLK stays low, and MOSI stays high. SCLK should be emitting a stream of 1's and 0's so it should cause and LED to flicker, but it doesn't. I've been able to make everything work with an Adafruit Feather M0, and these tests worked with that device, so it should be the same with the pi.

I don't have a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cmac                    3134  1
bnep                   11949  2
hci_uart               21222  1
btbcm                   7917  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             376017  24 hci_uart,bnep,btbcm
spidev                  7034  2
brcmfmac              269955  0
brcmutil                9911  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              527260  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 21373  6 bluetooth,cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            23131  0
snd_pcm                97889  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              22706  1 snd_pcm
snd                    68784  3 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
i2c_bcm2835             6433  0
spi_bcm2835             7424  0
bcm2835_gpiomem         3791  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         3718  0
uio                    10166  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
fixed                   3029  0
i2c_dev                 6642  0
i2c_bcm2708             5740  0
ip_tables              12512  0
x_tables               20921  1 ip_tables
ipv6                  384901  20
```

cat /boot/config.txt

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi0-hw-cs

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Enable UART
enable_uart=1


dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c=on
dtparam=i2c_arm_baudrate=100000
```

ls /dev/spi*

```
/dev/spidev0.0  /dev/spidev0.1
```

cat /etc/os-release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Also posted here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=202978&p=1261183#p1261183

I haven't yet tried running an older version of raspbian, that's what I'm starting on now. If that doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas.

Please help. Need to get this working ASAP.

[/EDIT]

Comment: How can we help when you have provided no useful information?

Comment: How can I give you useful information if you don’t tell me what information would help you? I lot of useful information was included in my post on the raspberry pi forums which I link to.